# Scheduling output exporting from HDFS to S3

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, hdfs, spark-streaming, s3distcp

Trying to figure out how to export data from HDFS which is outputted by Apache Spark Streaming job. Following diagram defines solution architecture:

[image: Solution architecture]

Apache Spark runs streaming job in AWS EMR cluster and stores result in HDFS. Streaming job collects data once every hour by using window functions and performs computations.
I need to export these results to S3 and RDS which I can do easily by running S3Distcp and Sqoop commands however I want these to be run exactly once each computation is complete.
I would like to do this more gracefully using something else than cron job.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can post a message to a SQS queue and do your job in a lambda.

Comment: What about Hadoop native components such as Oozie and maybe Airflow?

Comment: They are probably good tools to have a look at and investigate. We are not using them as we speak.